# I'm confused with this (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I was messing around with javascript as I am new to it and seeing how it worked.

why does this:

```
for(x=20;x>=1;x--){
document.write(x + x-- +", ");
}
```

write out the 4 times table backwards

I'm confused... :(

Comment: don't use `document.write`. It's from a JavaScript that's over 15 years old and is a low level pipe writing command. That aside, why have you written what you did? What do you think it should do and why? If that's what you think, look at your code, line by line, and write out what it does if you pretend to be the computer.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`, see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29). Use DOM methods instead.

Comment: Isn't this infinite loop?

Comment: @IvanSivak: Yep.  It will just keep printing `40, `.

Comment: Where are you running this and what output are you seeing exactly?  You claim it "[writes] out the 4 times table backwards", this is not true.

Comment: for some reason I pasted a different thing... just edited it now

Comment: @rowan: You are looping, starting at 20, then decrementing `x` by one after each loop.  Then inside the loop, you are doing `x--`.  If you didn't know, `x--` is the same as `(x = x-1)`.

Answer (score 2):

That is an infinite loop. It will output `40,` as many times as your computer can thrash (or browser) until causing an out of memory exception or timeout.

The reason it is an infinite loop is that you are decrementing your iterator in the for loop while incrementing it in the body.

This code is literally pointless.